# Get Current User Guilds Discord

Tags: api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use 'Get Current User Guilds' but I really don't know how to start, it required the guild scope and I'm aware of that so to actually use it please?
I'm trying to make it as a discord bot but I really have no idea on how to get the data out I believe it's an API like a curl request but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The guilds you are in are saved under bot.guilds, which you can iterate over. (or whatever you called your client)

Here's a bit of code I use to print a list of the names of servers I'm in, but they act like normal guild objects so you can do whatever you want with it.

```py
@bot.command()
async def serverlist(ctx):
    guildlist = ""
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        guildlist += guild.name + '\n'
    await ctx.send(guildlist)
```

Comment: what should be in the guildlist? the guild ids? or just an array with all the lists so it loops?

Comment: @D3sForEver The guildlist is nothing a string i use to send all guilds the bot is in in the chat. You could use every property of a guild within that loop. What you loop over is nothing but a list of guild objects. Some more information about what you can do with those object you can find here (spoiler alert, you can do a lot) https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?guild#guild

Comment: So I don't need to use anything or input anything I just need to use the command right?

Comment: @D3sForEver well that command is just an example of what you can do with it, discord.py keeps a list of all the guilds you're in and keeps it up to date for you, so you can just use the bot.guilds where it is saved to do operations on all the guilds you're in. In the command I get the names and put them in a list, but that is a very basic usage of it, you could get members, channels, everything in a guild and do whatever further calculation/operation you want with it.

Comment: but wait, does this command tell me about a user or about the bot?

Comment: What I really want is 'Get Current User Guilds' and to use the "Guild Scope" not to get in which servers the bot is

Comment: @D3sForEver Wait, do you want to know every guild a certain user is in? I'm afraid that is completely impossible, the discord api's Get Current User Guilds is only for the user for which the session is made im pretty sure, aka your bot

Comment: no not entirely, check this out, https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds, if the user when he added your bot gave you the Guild scope, you can somehow see in which servers he is

Comment: @D3sForEver I'm not too sure about that. I do however think that discord.py is just for making a bot aka the bot scope. I have no idea how exactly other scopes work with an application, but I am pretty sure of the fact that you can't get that with just your normal bot 'invite'.

Answer (score 0):

You first make the api call to the authorization endpoint with a `scope=guilds` parameter, this returns an token from the user. After that you can make an request to the users guilds endpoint with a Bearer token header having the above created token

`api/users/@me/guilds`